# The JUnit test suite failes with [junit] ASSERTION FAILED: 'ci->bp_id == 0'

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins, junit, automated-tests

I have a JUnit test suite running on Jenkins.
The test suite uses the below technologies.
Ant to build
JMockint to Mock the EJBs
Jacoco for Code coverage

The test suite runs one a Jenkins Slave machine (unix), and runs for an average time of 45 mins (~1500 tests).

The test count in the suite  gradually getting increased. Form recently I get the below error making the test run crash intermittently.

```
[junit] 
[junit] ASSERTION FAILED: 'ci->bp_id == 0'
[junit] In cmReleaseCodeInfo() (src/jvm/runtime/code/memory/codecollector.c:454)
[junit] Assertion failed after 0 days, 00:32:50 on Mon Jan 23 11:14:50 2017
[junit] Running requires.testMis.MaskedCinTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] Tests FAILED (crashed)
```

I'm not sure how to trace this.  Would be glad if anyone has a clue/ or a lead to find whats going on.

Would be more interested to see  from where `[junit] ASSERTION FAILED: 'ci->bp_id == 0'` is coming.

Comment: Have you had a look into that file mentioned in the assert? Maybe that gives a clue what it is about?

Comment: I could not find this file. In fact I have a java project. The file showing above is **C**. This looks much more like lower level than Java.

Comment: Also the assertion shown above, I have not coded such in my project.

Comment: This is coming OUT OF the JVM itself. And the sources should be open source!

Comment: Correct @GhostCat, I was thinking this is more like C code within Java .. ?

Answer (score 0):

> Would be more interested to see from where [junit] ASSERTION FAILED: 'ci->bp_id == 0' is coming.
>
> I could not find this file. In fact I have a java project. The file showing above is C. This looks much more like lower level than Java. – Asanke 8 hours ago
>
> Also the assertion shown above, I have not coded such in my project. – Asanke 8 hours ago

The assertion is compiled into a binary executable your code uses.

There are different approaches obout how to deal with this situation depending on what type of test you are executing.

If this is a regression test (or acceptance test) you may have discovered a bug: your code passes an invalid `bp_id` (what ever this is, you should know...).

If this is a UnitTest then you should mock the code that calls the binary executable.

Comment: Thanks @timothy-truckle. This is regression test. But the failure is not consistent. The test suite run fails intermittently.  Also I'm not sure how to translate my java code in to 'ci->bp_id == 0' assertion, as the variable name s I see is no way related to my variables in test code.